# Is it correct to say "no need of thanks"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage, colloquial-language

Is it correct to say "**no need of thanks**" when someone says "thank you"?

I think you're welcome, no problem, any time and nothing at all are quite often.

And I think no need to say thanks is also more appropriate.

But is it awkward to say no need of thanks?

I've searched about it but I couldn't find any results.

Could you please explain?

Comment: Years back in India, *thank you* was replied with *mention not!*

Comment: @MaulikV Still it's in use in India. But isn't it wrong?

Comment: There are many such things..but the problem is when the entire *mass* practices, it becomes a *norm!* And, you know, we *exceed* everywhere when it's *volume!* :) For instance, *picturization* we used a lot...now it's getting grounds!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There is no need **for thanks**.

Here, *thanks* is a noun.

> There is no need **to thank me**.

Here, *to thank* is a verb.

In the same way:

> There is no need **to be sorry**. (verb)

or

> There is no need **for sorriness**. (noun, though I doubt anyone would actually say this.)

Comment: For that last one I also doubt anyone would actually say this - they'd say  *There is no need **to be apologetic*** (or more likely one of *There is no need **to apologize*** or *There is no need **for apologies***).

Answer (score 3):

"No need of thanks" is apparently a construction that others have used, but it's astonishingly rare, at least according to [this Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+need+of+thanks%2C+no+need+to+thank&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20need%20of%20thanks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20need%20to%20thank%3B%2Cc0). As you can see, "no need to thank" (somebody) is a much more common way of putting it. 
You could also say "It's nothing" or "My pleasure" if you want to indicate that thanks aren't necessary.